# Area enclosed by curves

Tags: integration, area

Given the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}(x+x^4)$. What is the area enclosed by them ?
I can't find the points of intersection of the curves.

Comment: Check if at $x=1$ there is an intersection. Then use that information to factorize something in a proper way.

Comment: Also $x=0$ is an intersection.

Comment: These curves intersect at $4$ points: $\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2},0,\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},1$

Comment: [Plotting the curves](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x^2+and+y+%3D+1%2F2*%28x%2Bx^4%29) might help you to have a better idea of the problem and to find all intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\begin{align}x^2\ge \frac{x+x^4}{2}&\iff x^4-2x^2+x\le 0\\&\iff x(x-1)\left(x-\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)\le 0 \\&\iff \frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{2}\le x\le 0\ \ \text{or}\ \ \frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}\le x\le 1,\end{align}$$
the area is
$$\int_{\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{2}}^{0}\left(x^2-\frac{x+x^4}{2}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}}\left(\frac{x+x^4}{2}-x^2\right)dx+\int_{\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}}^{1}\left(x^2-\frac{x+x^4}{2}\right)dx.$$
Here, use $x^2=-x+1$ for $x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$.